# Sunmi v2 pro cannot print external printer with bluetooth

Tags: bluetooth, thermal-printer

I connected with bluetooth to external printer within sunmi v2 pro. Bluetooth works okay. Application stop when I print with that connected external printer.

My external printer is TSP143IIIBI. Star
Can I connect and print with that printer in sunmi v2 pro?

Answer (score 1):

It causes because of sunmi SDK version.
Not work in 1.1.0 of Sunmi SDK Version.
It will work the upper version of that.
Thanks.